# How can I escape '/' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

If I try

```
escape('/')
```

It just returns the same thing. Is there some function available that can escape the '/'?

Comment: What exactly would an escaped `'/'` look like?

Comment: Is this as part of a regex? Could you add a bit more info to the question?

Answer (score 3):

I think that you mean you want to urlencode it. Try  `encodeURIComponent('/');`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if this is used in a regex you can prefix it with `\`.

```
foo.test(/\black\/white/) // foo = 'black/white'
```